# Erro na tratativa de horas no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema para realizar a adição de tempo em um campo no mysql.
Ao utilizar a função

> date_add(Chegada, interval ".$item[6]." minute)...
>
> ADDTIME(Chegada,".$item[6].")...

Os dois em uma determinada circunstancia, retornar o valor de '25:00:00' na qual deveria retornar '01:00:00'. 
O mysql possuí outro método para calculo de tempo ?

Comment: Qual é o valor que está recebendo em **Chegada** e qual o valor que está passando de `$item[6]`?

Comment: UPDATE viagem SET Saida = ADDTIME(Chegada, '01:30:00') where id = 4518
Chegada   23:30:00                
 Saida 25:00:00     
Tempo    90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
// (23 horas e 30 minutos + 90 minutos) / (24 horas)
TIME((ADDTIME(TIME('23:30:00'), SEC_TO_TIME(90 * 60))) % (TIME('24:00:00')));
```

Sendo no seu caso, conforme você informou no comentário:

- Chegada: **23:30:00**
- Tempo: **90** (minutos)

```
TIME((ADDTIME(TIME(Chegada), SEC_TO_TIME(Tempo * 60))) % (TIME('24:00:00')));
```

Comment: Deu certo 
Valeu Vinícius !

Comment: @welliton Fico feliz por ter ajudado! Por favor, não adicione "obrigado" nos comentários. Em vez disso, vote a favor das respostas que você achar úteis. :D

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer com que essa hora seja gerada, no momento da insert, no banco de dados mysql.

colocando esse codigo ("timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP") a frente de uma coluna DATADECASTRO (EXEMPLO), com isso quando você inserir ele automaticamente pega a data e a hhora que for inserido no banco

Comment: Ele tem uma hora pra saída e um tempo em tempo em minutos para chegada, com isso eu preciso converter esse minuto em horas para adicionar no campo chegada.

Comment: A sim, então não irei poder te ajudar, me desculpe acabei entendo errado oque você queria!!

Comment: Sem problemas, muito obrigado !